# How to stack multiple notification together correctly?

Tags: android, notifications

### Background

Suppose I have some events that cause to show a new notification.

Instead of showing a totally new notification (with a different ID), it's recommended to stack them together, as written [**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) and [**here**](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) , so you actually replace the previous one.

example of a stacked notification:

[image]

As an example (and it's just an example, so please don't stick to it), let's take Gmail. if you get an email, a notification is shown. if the user clicks it now, it will go straight to the message itself. However, if more emails have arrived, the notification is replaced with a stacked one that when clicked will just go to the emails list activity. Not only that, but the notification also shows the number of new emails.

### The problem

Once you show a notification , you don't have any control of what is shown there. you just replace it and you don't know what was in it before.

The problem arises where you wish to stack multiple notification together to a single one, and still show some information about the previous ones.

Also, according to the documentation, the "[**setDeleteIntent**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent%29)" function is used only when the user dismisses the notification explicitly :

> Supply a PendingIntent to send when the notification is cleared
>   explicitly by the user.

### The question

Is it possible to get the previous notification's data when you replace it with a new one?

What is the recommended way to manage the notifications, so that a single one would have an intent of a specific type and data (when being clicked) and a stacked one would have a different intent ?

Do apps that use stacked notifications really manage a DB behind it, and also monitor the state of them somehow ?

Comment: You can hide notifications, you can show notifications, that is all. Notifications hosted in another process, that is why.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to a visible notification.

As explained in paragraph **[Updating notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating)**, you can access to a visible notification created by your app, using the same **notification id**

```
mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
int notifyID = 1;
mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New Message")
    .setContentText("You've received new messages.")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_status)
numMessages = 0;
// Start of a loop that processes data and then notifies the user
...
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(currentText)
        .setNumber(++numMessages);
    // Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is
    // updated.
    mNotificationManager.notify(
            notifyID,
            mNotifyBuilder.build());
...
```

I also suggest to save on local Sqlite database the information about the unread notifications and delete them once they have been read.

Comment: When your notification simply canceled, its intent is not delivered by system. It is good to purge them from database eventually.

Comment: what you show here in the code is setting a new notification. how would you get the data of the previous one, to stack it into the new one?

Comment: You have to save somewhere the data about unread notifications, for example in a database.When the user tap on the notification you have to clear all the records.

Answer (score -1):

This piece of code enables you to see all notifications received and cancels particular notification only when u cancel it.

```
Random random = new Random();
int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
Notification n = builder.getNotification();
n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;        
nm.notify(m, n);
```